# Fourier representation of delta function

Tags: fourier-transform, analyticity

As is well known the integral,

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-T}^{T} e^{i\omega t} \, {\rm d}t = \frac{\sin(\omega T)}{\pi \omega}$$

converges to $\delta(\omega)$ as $T\rightarrow \infty$ in a distributional sense.
As I think $\omega$ has to be real, how far is this representation valid in the sense of an "analytic continuation"?

Having a function $f(x)$ defined on the real axis which has a Taylor expansion, it is natural to get the analytic continutation by $x \rightarrow z=x+iy$.
However in this case the integral is not convergent for complex $\omega=|\omega| \, e^{i\epsilon}$ with fixed $\epsilon$ as the RHS is badly divergent.

Still I sometimes see people in physics arguing by Wick rotation that the line $[-T,T]$ in,

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-T}^{T} e^{i\omega t} \, {\rm d}t$$

can be rotated to complex $T$, e.g. the imaginary axis. But for such a rotation, the integral over the arc $[-T,-iT]$ would have to vanish, which does not happen.

Therefore in my opinion this is not possible, meaning that a distribution like that can not be analytically continued. Or does anyone have an idea what sense to make of $\delta(i\omega)$ for real $\omega$?

Comment: I'm voting to migrate to math SE, because while you are touching on a confusion that may arise due to practices in physics, the post is essentially devoid of physics content, and most appropriate for the math SE.

Comment: If that helps to solve the confusion :-)

Comment: Yes, you'll get a rigorous answer, and anyone here that can provide one also has an account on the math SE anyway :)

Comment: Why would you expect the analytic continuation of $\delta(x)$ to make any sense?

Comment: Isn't this what happens for example in (2.10) in https://arxiv.org/abs/1707.07702 ?
The euclidean version of the rotated pathintegral?

Comment: Anyone has had a look into the paper?

Comment: There's not any confusion in Physics, so far.

Comment: What do you mean? Can you maybe elaborate?